# How to open form when a specific cell on DataGridView double-clicked in visual basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView`, more like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   a   |   b   |   c   |   d   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   1.  |   b1  |   c1  |   d1  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The problem is how to make a cell ex: **b1** click and a form will show? but when **c1** or **d1** clicked the form won't open, the only cursor on the place **c1** or **d1**.

I already use `CellClick` event but all of the cells when I click will open the form, that's not what I want.
I use `VB.NET`.

```
Private Sub DgvUMutasi_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvUMutasi.CellClick
        Pegawai.ShowDialog
End Sub
```

Comment: You should check what is the column where the click happens. It is in the second argument you receive _e.ColumnIndex_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
Private Sub DgvUMutasi_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvUMutasi.CellClick
    Dim columnName As String = DgvUMutasi.Columns(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Name

    if columnName = "b" then
        Pegawai.ShowDialog
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: @Codexer - Where ?

Comment: On your class or at project level, if so that wont compile. `sender` is an object, it doesnt know about `columns`...

Comment: I guess you are suggesting the OP, i am just giving him few lines of code to use in his project, thanks.

Comment: I understand, but the few lines of code you gave will not compile if strict is on... You are relying on implicit casting...

Comment: Code is updated, you could say the problem in your first comment :) Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. @Md. Suman Kabir.... it really really help... thanks God you understand what i mean